# Is it safe to migrate a NVMe SSD to a new computer?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssd, linux-mint, nvme

I'm running Linux Mint 20 from a Samsung NVMe SSD on a Intel system (Broadwell CPU, H97 mainboard).
My plan is to make the switch to a AMD Ryzen system.
I checked the kernel compatibility with the new Ryzen hardware, which turned out to be fine, only Radeon GPU drivers need to be installed in addition.

Can I simply remove the NVMe SSD from the old system, install it into the M.2 slot of the new system and boot from it like it was possible with SATA SSDs and HDDs in the past?

Comment: The only issue might be drivers. The system might struggle to boot, resulting in a hacky migration or a need to format the drive and re-install the OS.

Comment: @spikey_richie I'm aware that driver issues might occur, like the need to install Radeon drivers. I was just wondering if there any implications on the mainboard/BIOS level, when the NVMe SSD comes from a different mainboard.

Comment: No, the other board won't have obtained parental responsibility to the drive. Once you remove it, it's an orphaned child looking for a new home to move to. Your new board is willing to be a foster parent, assuming all the paperwork is in order.

Comment: A late comment that I hope would be helpful — with Windows you probably won't succeed, but with Linux you can expect it to at least boot. I did what you want twice in my life; once from a laptop to a virtual machine (using dd to capture the disk image), another time from a Haswell machine to a new Tiger Lake one. Both operations worked seamlessly, I didn't even have to reinstall drivers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, NVMe disks are fully self-contained – the controller, along with all data related to flash memory management (wear leveling, etc.), is on the device itself. Even though the protocol is different from ATA in several ways, in general the OS still sees an NVMe disk as a ready-to-use block device (and the PC's firmware does not get involved at all).